# preg_match_all return empty array

Tags: php, arrays, rss

i write php programe for finde .mp3 link from a web site rss

```
     try{
        $con = new SimpleXMLElement('http://www.taktarane.ir/feed',NULL,TRUE);
        foreach ($con->channel->item as $items) {
            $content = $items->children('content', true)->encoded;
            $newReg = "/(http)(s?)(\:\/\/)(www\.)(.{5,120})(\.)(mp3|zip)/i";
            preg_match_all($newReg, $content, $matches, null, 0);
            print_r($matches);
        }
    }catch (Exception $ex){
            echo $ex;
    }
```

However, it return empty array!!!
        Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)

However i test in http://regex101.com/ it has 35 match result !!

Comment: `->encoded`? As in URL encoded? If that's the case, your string might well be `http%3A%2F%2Fwww....`, which your browser is rendering back to normal `http://www...` for display purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Simply leave the 2 last parameters. The parameter flags must not be null, but either PREG_PATTERN_ORDER or PREG_SET_ORDER

```
  preg_match_all($newReg, $content, $matches);
```